# undefined method `best_in_place' in Class in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

I follow http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast
for text inline editing

gem 'best_in_place'

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

But when I write

```
<%= best_in_place product_comment, :description %>
```

It gives error undefined method `best_in_place' for #<#:0xb43cc3dc>

Comment: Did you include the gem as well and ran `bundle install`?

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: normal form without `best_in_place`, is that is working ? suggest to share controller action code as well. you might be having instance variable as @post_comment in controller. can you check that too ?

Comment: Server not started thanks @BroiSatse

Comment: It works fine but how can I give custom styling to that field which appear after click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason why you could get this error (apart from other crazy reasons like dynamic undefining of methods in your code) is that `best_in_place` gem has not been loaded. Just restart your server and all should work

Comment: It works fine but how can I give custom styling to that field which appear after click?

Comment: I would say this is a different question. I never used this gem before so I won't be any help here but most likely you should be able to define your own css to override defaults.